# When using a CLLocationManager function, what is the "course" when in the "Locations" variable

Tags: swift

Im use thing a CLLocationManager function to find a uses location and follow them on a map.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    println(locations)

    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    var latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude

    var longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees  = 0.01

    let longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)

    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}
```

On the println command, it gives me this output:

```
[<+37.55337670,-122.37778690> +/- 5.00m (speed 36.15 mps / course 330.47) @ 7/15/15, 8:08:44 PM Central Daylight Time]
```

What I am wondering is what is the "course" output. It must have something to do with speed because it is in parenthesis with speed.

```
(speed 36.15 mps / course 330.47)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the heading (direction of travel).

See:

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/course

Comment: Please do not confuse heading with course, as those are two distinct properties. Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/GettingHeadings/GettingHeadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH5-SW1